# PHP unknown character in string

Tags: php

While calling an HTTP API i get a string of integers as result. the var_dump of the same is like below

```
string '﻿249139110' (length=12)
```

But this string have some invisible characters along with it. I tried the below code

```
foreach (count_chars($id, 1) as $i => $val) {
   echo "<br>There were $val instance(s) of \"" , chr($i) , "\" in the string." . ord($i) . " : " .gettype($i) ;
}
```

and the result i like below

```
There were 1 instance(s) of "0" in the string.52 : integer
There were 3 instance(s) of "1" in the string.52 : integer
There were 1 instance(s) of "2" in the string.53 : integer
There were 1 instance(s) of "3" in the string.53 : integer
There were 1 instance(s) of "4" in the string.53 : integer
There were 2 instance(s) of "9" in the string.53 : integer
There were 1 instance(s) of "�" in the string.49 : integer
There were 1 instance(s) of "�" in the string.49 : integer
There were 1 instance(s) of "�" in the string.50 : integer
```

Please help me to remove these � characters. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do a [`bin2hex`](http://php.net/bin2hex) to see what those are. (Perhaps NUL chars). Then trim, cast or regex-whitelist the string to an integer.

Comment: Trim the scring. Even the var_dump shows that it's longer than it is.
PS: also you can output $i and look it up in ASCII table, e.g. here https://ascii.cl/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW|FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH` and `FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW` will do the trick Try the code below

```
$unsafe='There were 1 instance(s) of "�" in the string.49 : integer';
$string = filter_var($unsafe, FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW|FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
echo $string;
```

Output will be:

```
There were 1 instance(s) of "" in the string.49 : integer
```

For more information read: [String sanitization through filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php)